# Find multiple column duplicates then list them all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I find database records which are duplicated like so :

```
select s.name, r.name Region, c.name Country
from supplier s
join region r on r.id = s.regionid
join region c on c.id = isnull(r.pid, r.id)
group by s.name, r.name, c.name
having count(s.name) >1
```

whats the best way to list them all (so if two duplicates it will appear twice etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create an in-line query from your Find-dups query and join to a "without-a-group-by" query.

```
select s.name, r.name Region, c.name Country
     from supplier s
     join region r on r.id = s.regionid
     join region c on c.id = isnull(r.pid, r.id)
     inner join (select s.name, r.name Region, c.name Country
                from supplier s
                join region r on r.id = s.regionid
                join region c on c.id = isnull(r.pid, r.id)
                group by s.name, r.name, c.name
                having count(s.name) >1 ) dups
     ON s.name = dups.name
        and r.name = dups.region
        and c.name = dups.country
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it:

```
with C as (
  select
    s.name,
    r.name Region,
    c.name Country,
    count(*) over (
      partition by s.name, r.name, c.name
    ) as ct
  from supplier s
  join region r on r.id = s.regionid
  join region c on c.id = isnull(r.pid, r.id)
)
  select
    name, Region, Country
  from C
  where ct > 1;
```